# Busted Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I have a motherboard with a capacitor busted. When I put the CMOS battery on it, it randomly reboots after a couple of minutes. The busted Capacitor has a rating of 6.3V 3300uf 150*c. But the problem is I have only a 16v capacitor woth the same capacitance but I know it will have ESR issues. But changing the busted capacitor with a capacitor with the same voltage rating but with higher capacitance will it work fine? Because I can't find the same rated capacitor on our local stores.

Comment: Since you already rebooted the PC with the busted one, what is the risk of actually trying to use the one you have?

Comment: I think the capacitor is connected with the BIOS/CMOS its hard for me to change the time again and again every time I reboot that's why I'm trying to fix it and I can't try it or risk it because its the only one I have.

Comment: ESR is critical for switching mode supply caps. A cap with too much ESR will overheat quickly and blast, too.

Comment: I have three capacitors: A 6.3v 4700uf, A 10v 3300uf and A 16v 3300uf. Which is the best replacement for the busted capacitor on my motherboard with a rating of 6.3v 3300uf? I can't really find a capacitor with the same rating,locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-critical parameters for this application are voltage rating > 5V, ESR and value of Cap which allows at least 1 minute to change the battery.

Critical values are the leakage resistance or C time constant of the Cap for giving at least 1 minute minimum battery replacement time. But this is not your problem.

Neither the battery condition or the capacitor condition should trigger a PC reboot in a normal design, since the PC being powered up also powers the Real-time clock and CMOS volatile memory.

*Impressions*:  No risk to trying a larger voltage rating cap.. No risk on ESR rating. But be alert for circuit contamination.  If this MOBO is more than 10 yrs old, maybe it is time to recycle it?

Comment: which capacitor will be better to be used a 10v 3300uf or a 16v 3300uf?

Comment: Probably the 16V will have lower leakage if both in the same family, but this is not your problem anyways...

Comment: what do you mean " lower leakage if both in the same family"?

Comment: e-cap leakage is rated in uA at the rated voltage.  e.g. I＝0.01CV or 3μA . where V is the rated voltage.  But since applied voltage is fixed, it wont matter. My main point was there is more differences in dielectric leakage among different part families.  e.g. a Rubycon PX is a family of same chemistry and construction of parts.